# Verify if Timeline is already created with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `timeline` in my spreadsheet but I want to verify if the timeline exists via VBA code.

How do I check if there's one?

Comment: You need to explain exactly what `timeline` is - for all we know it could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timeline is a [`SlicerCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercache) with a [`SlicerCacheType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercache.slicercachetype) of `xlTimeline`:

```
Sub FindTheTimeline()
    Dim cache As SlicerCache
    For Each cache In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        If cache.SlicerCacheType = xlTimeline Then
            Debug.Print "Got a timeline!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it work not as a single ```sub``` but as a part of a bigger sub? Maybe that's why I got nothing on the immediate window. It's the first time I use the immediate window so it could my fault. Also, whenever I ran the sub, even as a single sub, the only line executed apparently was the ```for each``` one, and then it just goes to ```end sub```. Is there a reason for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you. In testing, this identified a timeline for me. Do you have this code in the workbook containing the timeline?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using it inside of a module for a macro. This macro does a lot of things and in the end it was supposed to verify if there's a timeline and if not to create one. Like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-roentgen-j3cse?file=/src/index.js). Sorry for the editor, I simply wanted to show you my code.